# PyCharm Navigate to Python Source

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to be able to navigate directly to the python source code while I'm developing .

For example if I press F4 on a method in my project `Foo.Bar()` takes me to `function def __init__(self)` in class Foo, PyCharm opens that module and places me on the line where the method is defined . But , when I press F4 on `string.format(fmt_str)` I would like to be taken to

```
class Formatter:
    def format(*args, **kwargs):
        if not args:
            raise TypeError("descriptor 'format' of 'Formatter' object "
                            "needs an argument")
        self, *args = args  # allow the "self" keyword be passed
        try:
            format_string, *args = args # allow the "format_string" keyword be passed
        except ValueError:
            if 'format_string' in kwargs:
                format_string = kwargs.pop('format_string')
                import warnings
                warnings.warn("Passing 'format_string' as keyword argument is "
                              "deprecated", DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
            else:
                raise TypeError("format() missing 1 required positional "
                                "argument: 'format_string'") from None
        return self.vformat(format_string, args, kwargs)
```

which is in Python's source at /Lib/string.py

I don't know where the source to string.format() lives , so if this Formatter.format() isn't it , please don't tell me that , what I am trying to do is learn things like that and the implementation details of string.format() . This is simply an example of what I am trying to do , in order to improve my understanding of Python past a junior level .

Answer (score 4):

The function that you're trying to navigate to is implemented in C. PyCharm has no support for navigating to the source code of the standard library functions in the CPython source code.

Comment: Interesting and helpful , but not quite the correct answer . If , in Python , you can call list() , then in Python , there must be an implementation of class list . I have chosen a bad example and will correct that .

Comment: How do you know this is not a correct answer? I'm quite deeply familiar with the implementation of CPython. The list class is implemented in this file, which is written in C, not Python: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c

Comment: The implementation of string.format is [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l13791), which is also a C file.